# C# Training Quizzes

Tags: c#, c

I have been programming 10 years, mostly in vba and vb.net but I know c# well enough to program what I normally do. I yesterday was applying for a Senior c# position and I did so poorly on the induction test its not funny :)

I have always found that for me the best way to learn and recall is via questions and answers (multichoice and short answer). That is, a question is posed and after I answer instant feedback is given as to whether I choose right or wrong and the reasons why.

As such I was wondering if anyone knew of or could recommend a C# quiz website. Something like a daily c# quiz to keep my brain up to date and fresh if I'm not always programming in it. Not something wimpy either. Something that does everything. Paying is not an obstacle, id prefer to pay for a good resource than muck around.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of questions did they ask? Was it C# specific or .Net framework questions?

Comment: It was C# specific. It was mostly syntax related Q's that I'd never have needed to know about before, but I must admit after I knew I got the first 3 or so wrong I just skimmed through the rest knowing I wasnt gonna get the job :/ ... The role was a finance/algorythimic trading house.

At another place they gave me two different tests, one on .net framework and one on c#. I got top 15percentile for that but they were a lot simpler. That was an intermediate general line of business type position tho which I guess is more where I am at.

Comment: http://skillgun.com/csharp-test/online-test Best C# Quiz ever From basics to advanced. Period

Comment: @vbp: Not bad for training, but some of the answers are wrong (I reported).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Are You Certifiable](http://www.microsoft.com/click/areyoucertifiable/) from Microsoft.

You have to register with a Windows Live ID to access all the questions.  The questions they have cover a range of programming technologies (includes SQL Server and sysadmin).  The questions are multiple choice and include a paragraph or two on why each response was correct or incorrect.

The site includes a cheesy point system with awards and badges.

Comment: lol, the tacky music and gameshow lights make this look promising :)

It crashed before I can get in tho...now its frozen on 2nd time...maybe I should upgrade silverlight like it asked.

I will report back once i have it working!

Comment: Besides the cheesyness that site isnt too bad. It's kind of what I'm after. I will see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: The content of that site is a little off what I was after but its not too bad. Thank you all.

Comment: I like this one the best as it covers a wide range of microsoft avenues; sql server; windows, web, mobile.  There really is so much to .NET and microsoft technologies that if you are not working with them 100% of the time, and all avenues, you may fail a test depending on what the test questions are geared towards.  This goes with any programming language though.

Answer (score 7):

Well its kinda like a quiz, but [this site is great.](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: You even get points for correct answers!

Comment: even better if you make it specific to C# - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

Comment: +1 for the lulz, -1 for ignoring "a question is posed and after I answer instant feedback is given as to weather I choose right or wrong and the reasons why." so I guess it balances it out.

Answer (score 4):

[**Project Euler**](http://projecteuler.net/) - you can do it in any language, and C# is certainly an option.

It's not precisely a 'quiz' - more like a large set of programming problems (challenges), but it will certainly keep your mind sharp if you work through some of the harder ones. Problems take the format of a simple question statement and an input box to enter the result of your program, upon which the website will give you instant feedback.

In my opinion, this is the best sort of challenge, since it gets you thinking for yourself how you might approach a problem imaginatively, and not simply program like an automaton.

Comment: Also http://codingdojo.org/ - see the Katas. I heard a nice presentation by Bobby Norton on Test-Driven Learning recently; my notes from it are at http://www.truewill.net/scna2009/norton.htm

Comment: It looks interesting thank you, but not really what I am after. Ideally I want the quiz so I CAN program like an automaton.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.QuiznetOnline.com

QuizNet Online allows developers who specialize in Microsoft technologies to take free online practice tests.The advantage of the QuizNet Online compared to any other similar site is that users can submit questions and answers in the form of multiple choice or true and false questions.This is very beneficial for job interviews and for exam preparations as these questions will come from different sources.
The free online practice includes C#, .Net Framework, SQL and ASP.NET as the default quizzes.

Other quizzes such as Biztalk and VB.NET will be added as future practice tests.The concept of this site is that the questions and answers is maintained by any users of this site.

email:contact@quiznetonline.com

Answer (score 3):

Hidden features of C#..., this is a great thread to find out all kinds of stuff you don't know but probably should

[Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)

Comment: Interesting list...lots I dont know about there! All it does is stress me out tho :) A quizzy kinda helps to split it up. Do I sound like a wimp?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try http://www.quiznetonline.com. It has about 1300 .net related questions (C#, ASP.NET, General .Net and SQL questions) and users can even save questions for their own quiz. It also allows you to see how other people are doing on the questions and also tracks your score so you can over time see if you improve.

Answer (score 1):

My 2p.
I'd recommend buying a decent book on C# or looking at a lot of the excellent articles on the web - a quick google will return you a wealth of good results ( I've stuck some links at the end ).
A quiz won't teach you c# - you need to use it and learn it then you'll find any interview questions a lot more comfortable

[c# in depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Default.aspx)
[c# tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx)

For more back end and 'show off' in interview stuff then check out
[Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/)

Comment: What a quiz helps me do is remember it. I dont use 100% of any language I develop in on a daily basis. Im fairly intelligent but no genious and quiet frankly after 10 years my hippocampus has been kind of abused. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here are two quizzes which might help you
 [C#  quiz](http://www.skill-guru.com/skill/login/testDetails.faces?testId=43&testName=C#-Interview-questions) and 
[.net quiz](http://www.skill-guru.com/skill/login/testDetails.faces?testId=42&testName=Net-Interview-questions)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at the Microsoft certification docs/books, or just getting a good, general purpose book on C# programming.  The books might intimidating to get through, but I think it's worth the time - they'll give you a more broad coverage of all the material, whereas the quiz sites will only give you a selected few things, and might miss something that another quiz covers.

I've read books from these publishers, and they all seem to be pretty good:  O'Reilly (animal pics on the covers), Apress (black and yellow covers), Manning (books with strange paintings on the covers).

Comment: I dunno. When I read books, and I've read many of them I find the information doesnt stick. They are good for overall general stuff but the finer stuff is what I like quizies for. 

I suppose I know what I dont know....theres a whole bunch of stuff I dont know. How do I know that? I read books and the internet more than actually coding :)